# Raising an event from within a ObjectModel.Collection(Of T)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, class, events, collections

I have a collection defined as follows:

```
Public Class cData_X_Collection
    Inherits ObjectModel.Collection(Of cData_X)
End Class
```

This class is used in ListView on a WPF form and works correctly.

The cData_X class has an event:

```
Public Event SendCheckBoxChange()
```

How do I catch that event (when it is raised) in cData_X_Collection?

Comment: What exactly should happen when a collection item raises that event? Should it be handled by the derived collection type, which will subsequently raise another event, or do you want something to happen in the related ListViewItem?

Comment: The code that handles the event is going to iterate through the collection and count the number of cDate_X objects that are set a certain way.

After that, yes, the collection class will raise an event returning the counted number of items.

Just curious, why does it matter WHAT i do with the event?

Comment: It matters a lot when people try to understand what you're going to do. Do you know how to override the four virtual methods InsertItem, SetItem, RemoveItem and ClearItems, as explained in the second example in [Collection<T> Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx)? You would have to do that and attach or detach your event handler to/from the added or removed collection items.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that in 

   Protected Overrides Sub InsertItem(....

I need to "attach" an event handler for the item just added?
(And the opposite for removing.)

Ok, then next question.  In Example 2, an event is raised in InsertItem that fires when an item is added ... but no event handlers are "attached" for the items added.  Can you point me to an example of this being done?

Comment: Then your questions is how to add or remove an event handler with VB? You may look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2).